# How do I append a SSH key with JSON for Google cloud compute VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vps, google-cloud

For the following *dummy* key, in relation to [adding ssh keys to a google compute cloud project](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide):

```
thufir@mordor:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 768 -f ~/.ssh/gcloud -C thufir
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/thufir/.ssh/gcloud.
Your public key has been saved in /home/thufir/.ssh/gcloud.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:pS6ohohbMBD4cQi+s19JyhCuYT+GeSx+uvhzcqnMb2s thufir
The key's randomart image is:
+----[RSA 768]----+
|+. .             |
|o.o .            |
|.+ o      .      |
|o +      o       |
|+*   .  S        |
|o+X o...         |
|+*.O.+. .        |
|*+OoE  .         |
|oBX@o.           |
+----[SHA256]-----+
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ nano .ssh/gcloud.pub 
thufir@mordor:~$ cat .ssh/gcloud.pub 
thufir:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAYQCy904Zqx4BvR+bXEH5wgdbO2B6pKem9ZV7yzouTP2XawO7y9xfGmKnxPoUrDbdc5l/MLSkOiXZd9o3UYwD3I+XfuSTg/1+S/QC5CACQxymiJWav3w+zCBVO5rSnr4IkOM= thufir google-ssh {"userName":"thufir","expireOn":"2018-12-04T20:12:00+0000"}

thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata <instance_name> --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=.ssh/gcloud.pub
Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<instance>/zones/<zone>/instances/<instance_name>].
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ ssh gcloud
The authenticity of host '<ip_address> (<ip_address>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0s0rx7SXvhpJHj1owMgPVBpNUojx8vZ5kR9erw3AujA.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? ^C
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ rm .ssh/
config      gcloud      gcloud.pub  
thufir@mordor:~$ rm .ssh/
config      gcloud      gcloud.pub  
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ ssh -v gcloud
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/thufir/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/thufir/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for gcloud
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <ip_address> [<ip_address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/thufir/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <ip_address>:22 as 'thufir@mordor'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:0s0rx7SXvhpJHj1owMgPVBpNUojx8vZ5kR9erw3AujA
The authenticity of host '<ip_address> (<ip_address>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0s0rx7SXvhpJHj1owMgPVBpNUojx8vZ5kR9erw3AujA.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '<ip_address>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thufir/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub
no such identity: /home/thufir/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub: No such file or directory
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Is the key wrongly formatted?  Am I not uploading it correctly?  I also tried variations on removing the `= thufir` after the `key_value`, or just the `thufir` and leaving the `=`.  I must be misreading the directions for adding a key which is generated through the ssh command because these directions:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILE_NAME] -C [USERNAME]
```

seem to create key incompatible with the directions, in that there's a trailing `= thufir`.  Should that be removed?

*This is just a dummy key, I deleted `gcloud` and `gcloud.pub`.*

Comment: Everything what goes after the key is considered as a comment in the ssh-side, so you can open it in your favorite editor and append what you need.

Comment: the `=` indicates the end of the key?

Comment: `ssh-rsa fdksl... ` the space after the base64 encoded string (usually ending with `=`).

Comment: aaargh.   including the **first** `=`? After?  Before?  Everything **including** the first `=` and later is a comment?  Wait, you're saying it's the **space** which starts the comment. ?

Comment: [ServerFault explains this, as well as the manual page](http://serverfault.com/questions/743548/what-significance-does-the-user-host-at-the-end-of-an-ssh-public-key-file-hold/743566#743566): *options*, **keytype**, **base64-encoded key**, *`comment`*. The fields are separated by space.

Comment: The '=' is (loosely speaking) filler.  The key format requires the length of the keystring to be a multiple of 3, so a key may end in 0, 1, or 2 '=' signs to achieve that.  However, it is still a necessary part of the keystring.