# how does a google cloud compute generated SSH key lookup the VPS instance?

Tags: ssh, dns, google-cloud

If I manually create a key, rather than using the gcloud CLI console, can I also configure the public key so that it will look-up the connection as this config seemingly does:

```
thufir@mordor:~$ cat .ssh/config 
# Google Compute Engine Section
#
# The following has been auto-generated by "gcloud compute config-ssh"
# to make accessing your Google Compute Engine virtual machines easier.
#
# To remove this blob, run:
#
#   gcloud compute config-ssh --remove
#
# You can also manually remove this blob by deleting everything from
# here until the comment that contains the string "End of Google Compute
# Engine Section".
#
# You should not hand-edit this section, unless you are deleting it.
#
Host <instance>.<location>.<project>
    HostName <ip address>
    IdentityFile /home/thufir/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    UserKnownHostsFile=/home/thufir/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
    HostKeyAlias=compute.<####>
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    CheckHostIP=no

# End of Google Compute Engine Section
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ ll .ssh
total 80
drwx------  2 thufir thufir  4096 Jul 28 04:00 ./
drwx------ 69 thufir thufir 36864 Jul 28 04:03 ../
-rw-------  1 thufir thufir   799 Jul 28 04:00 config
-rw-------  1 thufir thufir  1675 Jul 28 04:00 google_compute_engine
-rw-r--r--  1 thufir thufir   395 Jul 28 04:00 google_compute_engine.pub
```

In particular, the `HostName <ip address>` line is what allows `ssh <instance>.<location>.<project>`?

The lookup is **not** established through DNS?

see sort-of related question:

[How do I append a SSH key with JSON for Google cloud compute VPS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298825/)

Comment: Yes. But it might be possible to go through the DNS. You can verify that using `dfig <instance>.<location>.<project>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In particular, the HostName  line is what allows `ssh <instance>.<location>.<project>`?

Yes.  If your [ssh config](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) has a `HostName <ip address>` line for a particular `Host somealias` stanza, then DNS is not used when you `ssh somealias`.

---

Note that it is also possible to specify a FQDN for the HostName

```
Host abc
    HostName alpha.beta.nonexistent.com
```

in which case DNS is used, but on the `HostName`, not on the `Host` alias.  However, not relevant to your setup.